# How can I use Java to read a key value in an ini file that points to a text file?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, ini, watchservice

I currently have created a Java app that will read key values from an ini file. The key value is pointing to a directory using it's absolute path (example c:\temp). I am attempting to use the String variable of the key value convert it to a File variable, then use that variable in FileReader. The issue I'm having is that the watch service will start but when I modify the watch directory with the str.txt file it throws and error and doesn't run through the switch case statement. I have also tried to use the Path variable in the bufferedReader which is why you will see it in the try statement that also didn't work, I guess I should have know that.

here are the results:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
z:\java_apps (Access is denied)
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds;
import java.nio.file.WatchEvent;
import java.nio.file.WatchKey;
import java.nio.file.WatchService;
import org.ini4j.Wini;

public class readIni {
public static String iniPath;
public static Path directory;
public static BufferedReader br;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try {

        Wini ini = new Wini(new File("z:\\java_apps\\java.ini"));
        iniPath = ini.get("filepath", "filepath"); 

        WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();
         directory = Paths.get(iniPath);


        WatchKey watchKey = directory.register(watchService, 
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_MODIFY,
        StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_DELETE);

        while(true) {
        for (WatchEvent<?> event : watchKey.pollEvents()) {


        try { 
            //read text into buffReader from file 
            Path path = directory.resolve((Path)event.context());               
            File file = new File(iniPath);

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

            System.out.println(file);

            //create empty string, read file content line by line while the line is not empty
            String str = "";
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
            str= line;
            line = br.readLine(); 

            //begin switch
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the file is still open by the program when it tries to open and read it a second time?

That would explain the `access denied` message.

In that case I would suggest closing the file at the end of the read.

Comment: I have a br.close(); in the program before the catch block of the inner try, however it never reaches that point because the text within the document triggers a response in the switch statements which never happens. Away from the read ini code the watch service performs as it should. It only fails when I attempt to use the ini value key to point to the file versus hard coding the file name into the FileReader. I want to be able to update the ini file which will prevent me from needing to go back an re-code the file statically. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by creating another entry in the ini file that pointed to the text file. I created another String to point to the text file instead of using the iniPath variable which must be used by Paths.get(). Originally, I was using inipath as the text file string which was giving me the errors.

```
 try {
     //outter try 
     //read ini file create, instantiate variables
    Wini ini = new Wini(new File("z:\\java_apps\\java.ini"));
    iniPath = ini.get("filepath", "filepath"); 
    textFile = ini.get("file", "file");

Then later in the code

 try {
      //inner try
      //read text into buffReader from file 
        Path path = directory.resolve((Path)event.context());               
        File file = new File(textFile);
```